# How to pad version components with zeroes for OutputBaseFilename in Inno Setup

Tags: inno-setup

I have Inno Setup 6.1.2 setup script where the version `main.sub.batch` is formed like this:

```
#define AppVerText() \
  GetVersionComponents('..\app\bin\Release\app.exe', \
    Local[0], Local[1], Local[2], Local[3]), \
    Str(Local[0]) + "." + Str(Local[1]) + "." + Str(Local[2])
```

Later in the setup part, I use it for the name of setup package:

```
[Setup]
OutputBaseFilename=app.{#AppVerText}.x64
```

The resulting filename will be `app.1.0.2.x64.exe`, which is mighty fine. To make it perfect, I'd like to end up with form `app.1.00.002.x64.exe` with zero-padded components.

I did not find anything like `PadLeft` in documentation. Unfortunately I also fail to understand how to use my own Pascal function in this context. Can I define a function in `Code` section for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A quick and dirty solution to pad the numbers in the [Inno Setup preprocessor](https://jrsoftware.org/ispphelp/):

```
#define AppVerText() \
  GetVersionComponents('..\app\bin\Release\app.exe', \
    Local[0], Local[1], Local[2], Local[3]), \
    Str(Local[0]) + "." + \
      (Local[1] < 10 ? "0" : "") + Str(Local[1]) + "." + \
      (Local[2] < 100 ? "0" : "") + (Local[2] < 10 ? "0" : "") + Str(Local[2])
```

---

If you want a generic function for the padding, use this:

```
#define PadStr(S, C, L) Len(S) < L ? C + PadStr(S, C, L - 1) : S
```

Use it like:

```
#define AppVerText() \
  GetVersionComponents('MyProg.exe', \
    Local[0], Local[1], Local[2], Local[3]), \
    Str(Local[0]) + "." + PadStr(Str(Local[1]), "0", 2) + "." + \
      PadStr(Str(Local[1]), "0", 3)
```

---

*Pascal Script `Code` (like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34698256/850848)) won't help here, as it runs on the install-time, while you need this on the compile-time. So the preprocessor is the only way.*

Comment: I was briefly investigating where the Str is documented, in order to find if there is something like AddChar in freepascal, but drew blank. Anyway, the InnoSetup community on SO once again served the solution on a plate for me, thanks!